# Real chroot on a systemd machine

Tags: linux, systemd, chroot, x-server

I'm trying to get used to `systemd`, because it seems to be the way that Debian is going.

I want to run Xorg in a `chroot` on hardware, rather than using networking (which [seems to be](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_Root#Using_systemd-nspawn) the canonical way of doing it in a `systemd` container), because I don't want to install an X server on my host system.  I want the host to be a thin, low-maintenance OS.

It is my [understanding](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/changing-roots.html) that `systemd-nspawn` virtualizes `/dev`, and therefore does not allow access to hardware.

Running a standard `chroot` seems to work fine in practice, though I am not sure if there will be any subtle problems with this.

Aside from the guest having direct access to the hardware, **is running a "real" chroot on a systemd machine a bad idea**? If so, what problems will it cause?

If it *is* bad practice, is there a way to do this with `systemd-nspawn`; such as some "unsafe" flag?  I'm not finding one on the `man` page, but according to [this page](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/systemd-nspawn.html), there is a `--share-system` flag; which doesn't work for me.

Comment: No. It is the same as on a non-systemd machine.

Comment: @CameronNemo thanks. Poettering talks about how systemd does some PID isolation, so I wondered if that could cause any problems with a traditional chroot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The systemd developers are pretty against allowing `nspawn` to access real hardware as this quote from [Poettering](https://plus.google.com/+StephenMartin1893/posts/ZiuKCUcUjTk) says:

> Well, the way we see it containers are really about getting access to virtualized environments only, i.e. /dev should be mostly empty (modulo /dev/null, /dev/random and friends), and the container really never should get access to physical hardware. This will then of course not allow you to run an X server inside the container.
>
> Other container solutions do support passing through hardware from the host to the container, we just believe it's a bit out of focus for the simple tool nspawn is and should stay.

A "standard" install Arch Linux is systemd based and the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_root) says nothing about a traditional `chroot` as being bad. Assuming that a traditional `chroot` meets your needs on a non-`systemd` system, then it should be fine on a `systemd` system. There may be situations in which the additional "virtualization" of `nspawn` is helpful, but there may be cases where it is limiting.

Comment: Thanks. That is kind of the impression I got-- I also hadn't seen anything about a traditional `chroot` being bad, but I didn't see anything about it being OK, either. [Here](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/changing-roots.html), Poettering talks about how `systemd` does some PID isolation, so I wondered if that could cause any problems with a tranditional chroot.  The focus of the article is on how `chroot` is broken, and `nspawn` is better, but it was unclear to me as to whether he was saying "don't do it at all".

Comment: ... also, the fact that packages like `schroot` aren't listed as conflicting with `systemd` is _probably_ an indicator that it's OK, but just wanted to get some more solid confirmation.